# how does a process know it's pages have been swapped out?

Tags: linux, memory, swap, virtual-memory, memory-management

Let's assume I have several processes running, a1 and a2. a2 takes so much space that physical pages belonging to a1 start to get swapped out. a1's page table has to be modified to reflect this. how a MMU determines which page table to modify? after all, p1 can belong to process a1 or a3. 
Also, what happens if it belongs to both (think shared library), can it be swapped out?

Comment: The process does not know - the page manager does. And that is no different for shared stuff.

Comment: It doesn't, and doesn't care.

Comment: the process doesn't know, but its page table does have to know, otherwise it would try to access physical page which may hold data from another process already.